# Getting the shortest angle path

Tags: math, geometry, shortest-path, angle, smallbasic

I need to get the shortest direction between two angles. Like if Ang1 is 5 and Ang2 is 355 then I want it to return that I need to subtract from Ang1 to get to Ang2 .

I have some code that will tell me the shortest distance, but not the shortest direction.

```
function getShortAngle(a1, a2) {

    let angle = (Math.abs(a1 - a2))%360;

    if(angle > 180)
        angle = 360 - angle;

    return angle;
};

console.log(getShortAngle(360, 720));
```

Or in Smallbasic:

```
Sub GetShortestpath

    angle = Math.Remainder((Math.abs(a1 - a2)),360)

    if angle > 180 Then
        angle = 360 - angle
    EndIf

    Return = angle
EndSub
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely that's just setting the direction based on which angle you choose.

If you're working out the angle/direction from `a1` to `a2`, the following pseudo-code should give you what you need:

```
# precondition: [a1,a2] >= 0
angle = ((a2 % 360) - (a1 % 360) + 360) % 360
direction = CLOCKWISE
if angle > 180:
    angle = 360 - angle
    direction = ANTICLOCKWISE
```

In cases where the difference is *exactly* 180°, it prefers the clockwise direction.

Forgive the complex expression getting the angle, it just to ensure you get a value 0 through 359 *regardless* of the relative positions and workings of your modulo operator with negative numbers.

You can greately simplify it if you make the precondition more restrictive, ensuring `a1` and `a2` are limited to the range `0..359`:

```
# precondition: 0 <= [a1,a2] <= 359
angle = (a2 - a1 + 360) % 360
```

Comment: That should do it! Thanks!