# JavaScript - Find turn direction from two angles

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have two normalized angles (between 0 and 360 degrees) and i want to find the shortest turn direction from point **a** to point **b**. (clockwise or counterclockwise). **a** or **b** can be anywhere on the circle, so the function should work in both way: if **a** is smaller and if **a** is larger than **b**.

I am wrote the following function, which works fine except when the shortest distance crosses the 0 degree mark:

```
function clockwise(a, b){

    return a < b;     

}
```

The function return **true** if it is clockwise and **false** if the direction is counterclockwise.

How can I get this to work for distances that cross the 0 degree angle? I am looking for an implementation specifically in JavaScript, since I wasn't able to translate any of the mathematical explanations I found. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308321/getting-the-shortest-angle-path

Comment: @Zock77 I tried this solution, but for me it doesn't work. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong translating the pseudocode, or if the logic does not apply to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but I think this gives the expected results?
(if `a=60, b=230` the difference is `170` and `clockwise=true` is correct..?!)

```js
function clockwise(a, b) {
  let clockwise, diff
  if (b > a) {
    diff = b - a
    clockwise = diff >= 0 && diff <= 180
  } else {
    diff = a - b
    clockwise = diff >= 180
  }
  return clockwise
}

console.log(clockwise(60,230))  // true
console.log(clockwise(220,150))  // false
console.log(clockwise(40,300))  // false
console.log(clockwise(120,214))  // true
```

Comment: I think this is the solution--it worked with every value I tested so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Relative to point a,

- Is clockwise, If b is present is in the next 180
- anticlockwise otherwise

```
function clockwise(a, b){
    let theta1 = b-a;
    return theta1 >= 0 && theta1 <= 180; // return true if clockwise
}
```

Comment: How do I interpret the result, to know whether point b is closer to a from the clockwise or counterclockwise direction?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I've tested this with a=120 and b=214 and got false as a result, but the closer direction should be clockwise (true).

Comment: If b is always bigger than a change to `b-a`, or `Math.abs(a-b)`  I'd say

Comment: Yup, sorry my bad. `b-a` gives the proper sign infact. updated the answer

Comment: @Corrl b can be smaller or bigger than a.

Comment: @Anil Now the function works like my original implementation. So a=60 b=230 returns true instead of false. I am trying to make it work both ways if a<b and if b<a.

Comment: @Ood, that's an important info that a might be bigger than b, it's best you add it to your question

Comment: @Corrl Sorry, I didn't realize this. Updated the question.